Testing iframes with Playwright/axe-core
I am working on accessibility testing with Playwright and @axe-core, following the instructions here. However, my webpage contains nested iframes and when scanning the page object as per the instructions, the incomplete property of the accessibilityScanResults object contains this:
    {
      id: 'frame-tested',
      impact: 'critical',
      tags: [Array],
      description: 'Ensures <iframe> and <frame> elements contain the axe-core script',
      help: 'Frames should be tested with axe-core',
      helpUrl: 'https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.9/frame-tested?application=playwright',
      nodes: [Array]
    }


This is the result regardless of whether I return the results of await new AxeBuilder({ page }) or await new AxeBuilder({ page }).include('#iframe-id')
The link provided under the helpUrl property says to "Ensure iframe and frame elements contain the axe-core script" but doesn't provide an example of how to achieve that.
How can I ensure the iframe contents are being properly scanned and assessed by axe-core?

Please share a [mcve] with the page under test.
